# ocaml getting syntax error

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I am getting syntax error on the line "module usingTable : TABLE =" and the word usingTable is highlighted red when I try to run this code in oCaml. I want to create table of the format as in the execution example bellow. What is wrong with it? The environment I am using is this one https://try.ocamlpro.com/fun-demo/tryocaml_index.html#path%3Dtries as I couldn't understand how to use cygwin or oCaml Bash in windows.

```
module type TABLE = 
sig
  type table 
  val emptyTable : table
  val printTable : table -> string
  val create_table : string * string list * (string list) list -> table  
end;;

module usingTable : TABLE =
struct
  let emptyTable = ()
  let table = (string * (string * string list) list) 

  let rec printTable aTable = match aTable with
      ()->""
    | (title, [data]) -> "\n"^title^"\n\n"^printTable(data)
    | [(col,cont)::t] -> col^"   "^printTable([t]) 
end;;

let atable = usingTable.emptyTable;;
let atable = ("Student", [("Id", ["2";"4";"7";"9"]);
                          ("Name", ["Jim";"Linnea";"Steve";"Hannah"]);
                          ("Gender",["Male";"Female";"Male";"Female"]);
                          ("Course",["Geography";"Economics";"Informatics";"Geography"])
                         ]);; 
print_string (usingTable.printTable atable) ;;
```

Comment: Where (on which line and column) do you get the syntax error?

Comment: On the line "module usingTable : TABLE = " the word usingTable is highlighted red.

Comment: Yes, because OCaml enforces that modules name start with an uppercase letter.

Comment: But this is not the only syntax error: for defining types (here, table) you should not use `let ... = ...` but `type ... = ...`

Comment: Thanks, this is my first ocaml program. I fixed those and the syntax error went to "(title, [data]) -> "\n"^title^"\n\n"^printTable(data)" highlighting red "(title, [data])" part.

Comment: As suggested by the detailed error message (that shows up when you move the mouse cursor to the red cross in the left margin) "This pattern matches values of type 'a * 'b but a pattern was expected which matches values of type unit" you can see that this is not a syntax error but a **type error** and it comes from the first branch `()` whose type is unit, so it is incompatible with `(title, [data])`.
Basically `()` is off-topic and should be replaced with `[]`, but this won't suffice for your code to typecheck: I'd suggest to double-check your type `table` and especially its parentheses...

Comment: BTW Have you read an OCaml course or a comprehensive tutorial before working on this exercise?

Comment: I have read slides of the course but those and the lecturers explanations are not that useful. My issue was how to encode the datatype (tableName,(colName,[colValue1, colValue2])) i.e. a list in a tuple that is in a list and all that is a one huge tuple...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170002/discussion-between-tosh-and-erikmd).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, you may want to take a look at some additional references before focusing again on this code example (which contained not only syntax errors but also type errors).

For example, I'd suggest the following links:

- the [official OCaml tutorials](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/), in particular you may first look at:

  - https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/functional_programming.html
  - https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/data_types_and_matching.html
  - https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/a_first_hour_with_ocaml.html
- the so-called [99 problems in OCaml](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/99problems.html) (a collection of quite standard exercises);
- the [Real World OCaml](https://dev.realworldocaml.org/toc.html) (an online book providing a comprehensive insight on OCaml);
- the official [OCaml reference manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/);
- and it might also be useful to have by hand the URL of the [doc of the Stdlib module](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Stdlib.html) (i.e., the module of the standard library that is always loaded by default);
- finally the [OCaml programming guidelines](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/guidelines.html) page may be of some help if you are looking for a compilation of "standard style recommendations / best practices".